# The set of reciprocals of positive integers and zero is open?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm working with a problem where we are given a metric space A that is defined as

```
                A = {{0} U {1/n}} such that n is a positive integer.
```

The problem asks whether or not the metric space is compact, and at what points the metric space is open or closed.

My intuition is that since R\A is open, then A is closed, and that the metric space is bounded at 
[0, 1/n]. Is it possible to use Heine-Borel here to show that A is closed and bounded and therefore compact? As for what the "open" points are, I'm not sure how to answer this other than to say that there are no open points, because all of the points in the set are singletons which must be closed.

Comment: $\Bbb R$ is not in the problem here, so $\Bbb R\setminus A$ is not an issue.  If $A$ is a topological space, it is both open and closed by definition.  What metric are you using?  That will determine what subsets of $A$ are open and closed.

Comment: The metric is the standard metric taken from R. The problem doesn't say anything about A being a topological space so I didn't follow that assumption.

Comment: Could you recite the exact definition of $A$?  As already demonstrated, the definition you have given is not fully clear.

Comment: Edited the post to include the definition of A, apologies for the lack of clarity.

Comment: Openness and closeness are properties of *sets,* not points.

Comment: From the context, I think you're asking whether $A$ is compact as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$? If so, then you can use the open covering of $A$ to show its compactness. I don't know if I understand you're question correctly... I can explain it in details if you want. @trotterr

Comment: Bounded at [0,1/n] is wrong.  A is bounded by [0,1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So $A = \{0\} \cup \{\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, and I suppose (though not mentioned) that this inherits the metric from $\Bbb R$, as it is a subset of it.

Then $A$ is compact (essentially because $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$):
Let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover of $A$. First find $U_0 \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $0 \in U_0$. As $U_0$ is open in the metric topology, there is some $r>0$ such that $B(0,r) \subseteq U_0$. Now find $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $N > \frac{1}{r}$, which can be done ($\Bbb N$ is unbounded above), and then for all $n \ge N$ we have $\frac{1}{n} \le \frac{1}{N} < r$ by standard facts about inequality and division. So all $n$ that are larger than $N$ lie in $B(0,r)$ and $U_0$.

Now, for all finitely many remaining $\frac{1}{n}$ with $n < N$ we can find (by definition of being a cover!) $U_n \in \mathcal{U}$ with $\frac{1}{n} \in U_n$.
By construction we now have a finite subcover $\{U_i: i < N\}$ of $\mathcal{U}$ and as the cover was arbitrary, $A$ is compact.

Looking at the above argument, we see that any neighbourhood of $0$ contains all but finitely many points of $A$, so $\{0\}$ cannot be open.

For points $\frac{1}{n}$ the situation is different: if $r_n < \min(|\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n}|, |\frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}|)$, so smaller than the distance between it and its (at most $2$) neighbours, $B(\frac{1}{n}, r_n)$ in $A$ is just $\frac{1}{n}$ and all points other than $0$ are isolated points, so open as singletons. And all singletons are closed in *any* metric space, showing that $A$ has many non-trivial clopen sets and is not connected, even totally disconnected.

Heine-Borel to show compactness is also an option: write $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ as a union of open intervals (so the complement is open and $A$ is closed in $\Bbb R$ and boundedness of $A$ is clear: $A \subseteq [0,1]$, say. But this $A$ is an illustrative case in which compactness can be shown directly by applying the definition of compactness. It's more elementary.